# How to import a Visio format diagram into draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, import

I've been trying to import a Visio .vsd file into the draw.io web application, without success. I've seen various online references to Visio import being supported, but no exact steps.

I've tried "File->Open From" and dragging and dropping the file into a blank diagram, but nothing appears to happen.

Answer (score 10):

[diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net) online supports the legacy .vsd format and the .vsdx format, which is the default format from the 2013 and 2016 versions of the tool.

The actual process of importing to either drag and drop the .vsd(x) file into a diagram, use "File->Import From", or "File->Open From".

[Note that only files exported from the actual Microsoft product are supported.](https://drawio-app.com/blog/import-and-export-vsdx-files/)